# What is the difference between Guest and Incognito modes of Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

I used the Incognito mode of Chrome for years, and it works pretty well. Recently I noticed they added "Guest" account, which as far as I could see, has the same features.

The only difference I noticed is that Incognito "remembers" previously visited sites for its URL auto complete, while Guest does not, but surely there are more differences?

What are those differences, in layman's terms?

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/chrome-guest-mode-incognito-mode/

Comment: @MátéJuhász saw that. "layman's terms" means I prefer short and focused answer, without 99% advertisements on the page, to figure what it all means. Everything is already said elsewhere, so if you're going to answer to everyone "here, it's answered in this other place" this site is totally useless, IMO.

Comment: it's layman's term for me, one paragraph per mode, written quite clearly. If you've already found it than it'd have been fair to include a link in your question and explaining what exactly your issue is with that. That way could have prevented wasting my time finding a reference which isn't useful for you. "Everything is already said elsewhere" - that's not true, there are a lot of original questions here. Having only unique content isn't the purpose of superuser, however just duplicating everything because you prefer to read it on superuser neither a good approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are more or less the same, but for different situations.

I'm going to assume you've read the relevant help pages for [guest](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6130773?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and [incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464) modes

Incognito mode is designed to be used *alongside* your regular profile on your own PC. It has access to your bookmarks and other profile information.

"Guest" is a profile on its own designed to be used to be used on a PC you don't control. It is seperate from any existing profiles.

The *big* difference is that your incognito window has the information from your current profile, and just dosen't save what you do in that window. Guest mode *both* restricts off information from other profiles *and* wipes anything you do.

Comment: In short, Guest is a separate profile that's always in Incognito mode.

Answer (score 2):

#### Guest mode knows nothing about your "Allow in incognito" extensions.

This is the biggest practical difference I've noticed.

Answer (score -4):

In guest mode every thing is visible to every one its means it is not protected but on tge other hand in incognito mode your browsing will be secure from others.

Comment: What do you mean "visible to everyone"? Who can see it and how? It does not save any history or permanent cookies.

Comment: OK, you don't want to explain. This makes this answer a low quality guess which is most likely wrong, and is not fitting as proper answer.

Comment: I believe if you visit a site over https even in icognito it is not visible (traffic is still encrypted).